# In Neural Network, why do we put minus in front of derivative while back-propagation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backpropagation, derivative

I'm studying on NN. I understood rough idea of how it works but there is still a thing that is not clear. Why do we put minus in front of derivative? Shouldn't it be just derivative in the case of derivative is negative by itself? I mean if the gradient of point a is negative already, then negative sign should not come. Isn't it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative in backpropagation is answersing this question:
*How **loss** (y) will change if I increase **weight** (x)?*

For positive derivative - to **decrease** loss we have to **decrease** weight. To decrease weight we just need to substract positive value.

For negative derivative - to **decrease** loss we have to **increase** weight. To do that we need substract negative value.

For both cases we need to substract value with the same sign as derivative.

`w1 = w0 - derivative`

Derivative is also answering question *How much loss will change?*
But it's not perfectly accurate, beceause it tells us how much, only for flat slope in current point. To better control how much we may use factor **learning rate**

`w1 = w0 - lr * derivative`